# Symfony2: How to pass a URL to a service (without passing entire router service)

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have a class/library which is written in regular PHP (For purposes of explaining lets call this "foobar" class). I am writing a Symfony2 Bundle for this to make foobar into a Symfony2 service and allow the class to be configured via config.yml.

The foobar class expects an associative array passed to the constructor, with one of the array elements been a URL. This URL I want to pass is derived from the Symfony router. I can't inject the entire router, I only want to pass the URL, I have included an sample of my current code which shuold make it easier to explain. it would be appreciated if someone could suggest the best practise for this situation.

***MySpecialBundle/Resources/services.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container ......>
     <parameters>
          <parameter key="foobar.class">...</parameter>
     </parameters>
    <services>
    <service id="my_special_service" class="%foobar.class%">
            <argument type="collection">
                <argument key="url" >%my_special.url%</argument>
                <argument key="another_arg">%my_special.another_arg%</argument>
            </argument>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

***MySpecialBundle/DependencyInjection/MySpecialExtension.php***

```
class MySpecialExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        //This is the URL that should be derived from the Symfony router
        $container->setParameter('my_special.url', 'http://this-url-should-come-from-router.com');
        $container->setParameter('my_special.another_arg', $config['another_arg']);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');
    }
}
```

In this file above, you can see that the URL is hard coded at the moment, but want that to be determined from the router (using a named route that this bundle also defines). How can I do this or is there a good alternative technique?

Please note, I am the author of the original library written in PHP, however I would rather not modify it to accept the Symfony2 router as an argument as I would like other developers to be able to use the library in other frameworks.

Comment: I see you're injecting the whole container into your service. What prevents you from from accessing the router with `$container->get('router')` ?

Comment: Why can't you just inject the router? The thing is, if you want to inject a generated route, at some point you are gonna have to generate it using the router, and that logic must be somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **expression language**. But it was introduced only from Symfony 2.4.

So, your definition should look less or more like this:

```
<container ......>
    <parameters>
        <parameter key="foobar.class">...</parameter>
    </parameters>
    <services>
        <service id="my_special_service" class="%foobar.class%">
            <argument type="expression">service('router').generate('some_path')</argument>
            <argument>%my_special.another_arg%</argument>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

You can read more about expression language here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language